# Walking out of shul backwards

Tags: halacha, tefilla, synagogue

When leaving *shul* after *davening*, I've seen some people walking out backwards.

Is this a *halacha*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Orach Chaim 132:5 Magen Avraham 6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=419) says that one should not walk out of the Shul with his back to the Heichal.

Comment: Is this a halacha or a recommendation?